# How can I load and execute external R scripts in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, r

I'm currently using rseve and the rserve-simpler gem.

1. I would like to load and execute external R scripts
2. Id like to pass data to and from the the R script and my rails app

Anyone with experience on how to best accomplish this. Im not tied to a specific gem/lib

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I've achieved this using the following code

```
# setup the data to be used by R scripts
r.>> "data <- c(#{out_data_points})"      

# Setup some params for plotting  
r.>> "png(file='#{Rails.root}/public#{plot_file_name}')"
r.>> "plot_name <- '#{self.name} : #{label}'"

# call the custom script      
r.>> "source('#{Rails.root}/app/rscripts/custom_script.r')"
```

I send R the data via the data variable and the script must setup variables in R that can be obtained via the converse method within the rails app. Also the images are sent to a specific dir with names dictated by the rails app and passed to the RScript.